# AutoHotkey - press Ctrl+Alt only, without any characters

Tags: macros, autohotkey

I can see that Ctrl+Alt+Delete is not possible with AutoHotkey, but what about just Ctrl+Alt?

Things I've tried:

```
; 1
#+y::
Send, {Ctrl}{Alt}
return

;2
#+y::
Send, {Ctrl down}
Send, {Alt down}
Send, {Alt up}
Send, {Ctrl up}
return

;3
#+y::
Send, {LCtrl down}
Send, {LAlt down}
Send, {LAlt up}
Send, {LCtrl up}
return

;4
#+y::
Send, !^
return

;5
#+y::
Send, {ctrl down}{alt down}{2}{alt up}{ctrl up}
return
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Ctrl and Alt and Shift are modifier keys. None of them have any value unless another key is provided that they can be used to modify.

Comment: The program I want to automate use of requires it. Pressing them manually does work, so where could the disconnect be then?

Answer (score 1):

The below will do what you want. It's also recommended you use `SendInput` going forward.

```
#+y::
SendInput, {Ctrl Down}{Alt Down}{Ctrl Up}{Alt Up}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the left or right ALT or CTRL keys

```
#+y::
Send, {LCtrl}{LAlt}
return
```